# Convert curl command line to php code - Error code 401

Tags: curl, cookies

I am trying to send this json data via php, and not having the best luck.

> curl -L -i -X POST -k --cookie ./cookies.txt -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"email": "longnp"}' https://sg-baas.acronis.com/api/1/actions/mail/activate/

Here's what I have:

```
$cookieDump = tempnam("tmp/", "cookies");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"email\": \"longnp\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieDump);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_URL,"https://sg-baas.acronis.com/api/1/actions/mail/activate/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 04:19:34 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag,Content-Length,Content-Type,Retry-After

Error 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: Did you get this success or not? How did you get cookies.txt file and what would be there in that txt file? Could you please share your ideas on it. Thanks!